# Creating an undefined Java array with limited values and a stop value?

Tags: java, arrays

I'm having trouble creating a array that will ask the user to enter a continuous list of numbers (my do while loop) that will be limited from 1-100. If the user enters anything outside these parameters, the value is not inputted into the array. If the user puts -1, it stops the do while loop. I need it to print out the values but it gives me only the first value and a loop. Please help me, thanks! PS: I cannot use an ArrayList

int count = 0;

```
do 
{
  input = userinput.nextDouble();
  if (input >= 1 && input <= 100)
  {
    array[count] = input;
  }
  else if (input > 100 || input < -1)
  {
    System.out.println("Please enter a valid mark (0-100)");
  }
  count = count + 1;
}
while (input != -1);

for (int counter = 0; counter < count; count++)
{
  System.out.println(array[counter]);
}
```

Comment: "I cannot use an ArrayList" Then, `LinkedList` may be useful.

Comment: Why are you doing `nextDouble` when it looks like an Integer is expected

Comment: nextDouble, I need to be able to use decimals.@ScaryWombat

Comment: @MikeCAT Not sure what that is, and I'm doing an assignment focused on arrays so I don't think I can use that.

Comment: you should use meaningful variable names. It helps a lot. For example, `size` instead of `count`.

Comment: That `else if` should just be an `else`- It is just the opposite of the conditions in the `if`, so becomes hard to maintain. What if you change the range from -50 to 50 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You incremented `count` instead of `counter` in the loop to print values, so the loop will go too many times and only the first element is printed.

Try this:

```
double[] array = new double[1000000];
int count = 0;
do 
{
  input = userinput.nextDouble();
  if (input >= 1 && input <= 100)
  {
    if (count < array.length) array[count++] = input;
  }
  else if (input != -1)
  {
    System.out.println("Please enter a valid mark (1-100)");
  }
}
while (input != -1);

for (int counter = 0; counter < count; counter++)
{
  System.out.println(array[counter]);
}
```

Also classes that inplements `java.util.List` is useful to store elements whose number is not known.

```
java.util.List<Double> list = new java.util.LinkedList<Double>(); // requires JRE >= 1.5
double input;
do 
{
  input = userinput.nextDouble();
  if (input >= 1 && input <= 100)
  {
    list.add(input);
  }
  else if (input != -1)
  {
    System.out.println("Please enter a valid mark (1-100)");
  }
}
while (input != -1);
Double[] array = list.toArray(new Double[list.size()]);

for (int counter = 0; counter < array.length; counter++)
{
  System.out.println(array[counter]);
}
```

Comment: A much better answer